# plugin com.apple.GameCenterUI.GameCenterMatchmakerExtension invalidated

Tags: ios9, game-center, multiplayer

Since iOS 8.0 my multiplayer game play works smoothly with GameCenter API. In iOS 9.0 when I tested I found the matchmaker at the middle is stopped, multiplayer not working and the following error shown.

```
plugin com.apple.GameCenterUI.GameCenterMatchmakerExtension invalidated
```

How to solve the issue?

Comment: I'm running into this issue now, were you able to resolve it?

Comment: I resolved it by fixing my previous code. Previously, in my code NSDictionary *loadedDict = [NSKeyedUnarchiver unarchiveObjectWithData:data]; if not valid archive file it throws exception which doesn't happen in iOS 9.0. So I add an if logic to check if it is nil or not. Thus solved my issue.